# Failing to apt-get update

Tags: apt, update

I've been scouring the net trying to find the answer to this and all answers that are close talk about not connecting to the net.  I have no problems on the internet, I am typing this on the pi3 that I'm having problems updating with.

I am hit with the following error upon attempting to update. Please help:

> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease 
>   Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release
>   file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

Comment: If I enter the address of the file into a web browser  i hit the file immediately.  http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease

Comment: i386 indicate that it is looking for the wrong architecture, a Raspberry Pi is a ARM based processor.

Comment: Ok...   That makes sense but how do I point it to the right architecture?

Comment: Lets diagnose first: `uname -m` shows the kernels arch. And what is the output from `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: And the outout from `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: armv7.1cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib 
#non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

Comment: dpkg --print-architecture  = armhf

Comment: dpkg --print-foreign-architectures  = i386

Comment: @MatsK Hi MatsK.  Can you take a look at the answers above?  I'd love to get this fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the i386 architecture since you are running a ARM architecture. But first you need to remove packages from the wrong architecture that have been installed:

```
apt-get purge ".*:i386"
```

And then:

```
dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

Ref.: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Comment: Thanks again.  And thanks for the link to educate me.   I appreciate your help.  @MatsK